Why is an amortized loan an annuity problem?
I am currently learning about amortized loans and my textbook models it as an annuity problem. For example, supposing someone takes out of a loan of $25,000, with an interest rate of 8% to be paid over six periods, the book calculates the PMT to be $25,000/((1-(1/1.08^6))/0.08) = $5,407.88 using the formula for the present value of an annuity.
I am perplexed. So far, I have only encountered annuity problems that boil down to someone depositing or withdrawing x amount of money into or from an interest-bearing account at regular intervals. In the case of depositing, the newly deposited x earns interest in the account, while in the case of withdrawing, the withdrawn money could have earned interest if not withdrawn so the future value of x is higher to reflect the opportunity loss.
However, with a loan, that is not what is happening, is it? Say you make a payment of x after the first year and you have y more years to go. In an annuity problem, the assumption is that x earns (or could earn) interest, and so its future value after y years is x(1+r)^y, where r is the interest rate of the investment.
However, with a loan, x is the amount repaid and therefore does not earn interest for the lender. Are we assuming that the lender takes the repayments and invests it somewhere else, and therefore it earns interest? Then that would be a typical depositing annuity problem for the lender, but we would need to use a different interest rate, not the one for the loan, right?
I must be misunderstanding something. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

I think your problem is thinking about that formula as being for an annuity, rather than being general interest versus principal over time.

One way to think about it is to equate to net present value (NPV) of the loan with the net present value of the payments (d), i.e.

The first payment occurs after one period.  Let's say the NPV of the first payment is $5007.30.  The interest rate on the loan is 8% so the amount that will need to be paid to meet this interest is $5007.30*(1 + 0.08) = $5407.88.
Likewise the last payment occurs after 6 periods.  If its NPV is $3407.88 adding the loan interest will require payment of $3407.88*(1 + 0.08)^6 = $5407.88.
Payment no.     NPV         d
    1         5007.30    5407.88
    2         4636.39    5407.88
    3         4292.95    5407.88
    4         3974.96    5407.88
    5         3680.52    5407.88
    6         3407.88    5407.88
             --------   --------
  Totals     25000.00   32447.28

resulting in total interest of $32447.28 - $25000 = $7447.28.
In applying the loan formula the cash flow NPVs do not need to be known.  They are included in the calculation as discounted cash flows: i.e. d/(1 + r)^k for k = 1, 2, 3, ... etc.
The loan formula can be derived from the sum of the discounted cash flows by induction :

where
  s = principal
  r = periodic rate
  n = number of payments
  d = payment amount

  s = (d - d (r + 1)^-n)/r
∴ d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n)

So with
r = 0.08
s = $25000
n = 6

d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = $5407.88

See also here: Calculating the Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity

If you make payment of x every year, then the third time you pay x, you are paying back x that you borrowed for three years (assuming the payments are at the end of the year). So that chunk of the loan accounts for x/(1+r)^3 of the initial loan amount. That is, if the loan had consisted entirely of a loan of P and only one payment of x after three years, then we can calculate that P is x/(1+r)^3.
For instance, if you take out a loan of $25k with an interest rate of 8% and pay $5,407.88 after three years, then that accounts for $5,407.88/(1.08^4) = $3,974.95, and there is $21025.05 left over. That is, you can think of this as two loan, one for an initial amount of $3,974.95 that's paid in one payment of $5,407.88 after three years, and $21025.05 that's paid back with the other five payments.
So what you can do is take the $25,000 and treat it as six loans, each of a payment of PMT. We can then relate PMT to the $25,000 amount: $25,000 = PMT/(1+r)+PMT/(1+r)^2+... We can then use the formula for a geometric formula to solve for PMT in terms of $25,000 and 0.08.
This formula for a geometric series applies any time we're adding a bunch of terms where each one is some constant amount times the previous one. That is the case for annuities, mortgages, and many other situations.

Thank you. Thinking about it as six individual loans helps a lot. Would I be correct in saying that an amortized loan is not an ordinary annuity then? It seems like it is only a coincidence that the formulas are they same; the rationale behind the formula for each case seems different.

A loan is certainly not an annuity; they are very different financial tools, for different purposes. However, both involve the time value of money at a presumed interest rate and so the same form of calculation applies; that tool can be used for either. Things can be modeled by the same formula without being the same thing.

In the simplest form a loan and annuity are the same.
When you get a loan from a bank: they give you a chunk of money and then you pay it back with interest. Once the balance reaches zero you are done. If you die they still want their money.
When you buy an annuity you give the bank a chunk of money and then they give you a monthly payment until you die. The size of the monthly payment depends on the interest rates.
There are optional additions that can make them term instead of forever, or allow money to go to a survivor. These options impact the size of the monthly payment. You can even buy insurance tied to the loan balance.
